# javascript replace string made of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i replace this string of characters in javascript? I need all occurences for this string inside a text.

String to be replaced: ^;)'(;

```
str.replace(/^;)'(;/g, "lsakdsalk"); does not work
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if one of these answers fit you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some characters have a special meaning. For instance `^` is the begining of the string.

Try to escape them:

```
str.replace(/\^;\)\'\(/g, "lsakdsalk");
```

Answer (score 1):

you should escape them with a backslash, example:

```
'\'';
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the characters in your string have special meaning within regex expressions and need to be escaped with a backslash so that they'll be treated as ordinary characters. For example, `^` usually matches the beginning of the string, but `\^` matches an actual "^" character. So:

```
str.replace(/\^;\)'\(;/g, "lsakdsalk");
```

Semicolons and apostrophes have no special regex meaning so they can stay as is. Parentheses do have special meaning so I've escaped them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `^` `)` and `(` characters in your regex:

```
var str = "^;)'(;";
str.replace(/\^;\)'\(;/g, "lsakdsalk");      // str = "lsakdsalk"
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace the string use `/\^;\)'\(;/g` To replace any of this characte `/[\^;\)'\(]+/g`